# Make .sh file executable

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, sh

I have a .sh file which is not becoming an executable. I tried doing it in the properties but as soon I ticked the checkbox, the tick vanished in a second.

I then tried

```
sudo chmod +x filename.sh
```

which returned nothing and after checking its properties, it dint turn into an executable. Any solutions?

Comment: Even if it isn't executable, I guess you can just "execute" it by `. ./filename.sh`?

Comment: Maybe the file is still opened in another program? Like gedit or another terminal.

Comment: @AlvinWong A closer approximation would be `sh ./filename.sh` - using `.` (equivalent of `source`) would parse it in the current shell, rather than spawning a subshell.

Comment: 1) @OP: Do you intend to run that script as uid 0 (aka toor, root, admin ,...)? If not, why use `sudo`? 
2) What happens if you open a shell, cd to the the directory the script is in and type `chmod +x filename.sh`?
3) What is the first line of filename.sh? Is that `#!/usr/bin/env bash` or similar?

Answer (score 3):

open the terminal and write the following command

```
chmod +x filename.sh
```

Well that gonna make your file executable which can be run from terminal by simple command

```
sudo ./filename.sh
```

There is another way of doing it through GUI, when you right click on the file and goto permissions tab then you get an option to make the file executable by just clicking a checkbox

Comment: I was just about to type the same thing. I suspect the "./" prefix was getting missed.

Comment: yupp tht was d error... and see that other way too. thtz more easy if you want to work just by GUI.

If yu found my answer correct, plz mark it as accepted answer :)

Comment: @Azzy I already tried what you said. Using the GUI, when I clicked the checkbox in the permissions tab, the tick vanished in a second. And when I tried what you said, it returned sudo command not found.

Comment: you don't need, and shouldn't use sudo unless you need to run it as root. Have you tried **sh ./filename.sh**?

Answer (score 0):

1. use gedit to write and save script with `.sh` extension to desktop.
2. open Nautilus and right click the `script.sh` file.

   - under properties, check box "allow executing file.."
   - in Nautilus menu, click file,then preferences,then behaviour
   - check the "run executable text files when they are opened".

Now, when you double click the file, it should execute.

Answer (score 0):

Check the immutability of the file with the extended attributes of the filesystem:

> lsattr script.sh

look for i attribute and remove it with chattr.